# Audio only on Left side with specific device

Tags: debian, audio

I am running a Debian 12 system (the problem was also on Debian 11) and I had to use hdajackretask to get one of my sound devices working, but for some reason it only gives audio on the left side. I don't know if it is because I am using a aux port or not, all of my other audio devices use Bluetooth, or USB. I will provide all the info I can if requested.

Comment: For sound issues I use the `pavucontrol` GUI tool. Consider downloading it and reviewing the settings and output devices.

Comment: Fco Javier Balon, could you please tell me which options in pauvcontrol might help me?

Comment: In the output devices section, there is a channel lock button (a padlock). By pressing it, you can see the specific configuration of each front (left and right). Maybe tt can be of some help.

Comment: Using channel lock did not work, I know the speakers work, they work when I plug them into my phone. Thanks for trying though.

Comment: Are there any other audio configurations that I could import that could fix it?